# How to connect from podman to a server running in localhost

Tags: podman

With docker-in-virtualbox I know that 10.0.2.2 is the host running Virtualbox and I can connect that way.

What is the analog for Podman running in QEMU? I am on MacOS Big Sur / x64 (installed through brew).

Answer (score 13):

Have a look into /etc/hosts in the container, there should be line like this:

10.88.0.1 host.containers.internal

The IP address will be different, but you can use DNS "host.containers.internal" instead.